# how to use my public ip with kestrel (asp.net core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I want to host an asp.net core 3.1 web api. I can make it run by using
`dotnet api.dll`
but it runs on localhost by default. I tried using
`dotnet api.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:8000` (checked that 8000 port is open) but still could not access it from my public ip. I think i have completly misunderstood how the whole thing works and i cant figure it out. This is supposed to be used in production (i work for a small company)

Comment: Is the public IP assigned to that specific computer, or (more commonly) to a router or network device somewhere?  If the latter, is it forwarding requests on that port to that computer?  This sounds more like a networking issue than a programming issue.

Comment: Could you please share your `configuration` how did you assign `IP`? Please have a look on the [`official document here for the correct configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-endpoints-using-server-name-indication-1)

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) it was indeed a network issue, the port. To any future googlers that arrive here make 100% sure that the port you are passing to your app is open and is not being used by another program.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've able to figure out the issue.